# How to inform TypeScript compiler of extensions to JS Array prototype?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, polyfills, tsc

I have created a polyfill for the JavaScript Array;

```
if (Array.prototype.remove !== 'function') {
    Array.prototype.remove = function (value) {
        var idx = this.indexOf(value);
        if (idx !== -1) {
            return this.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

Now I am upgrading the original JavaScript project to a TypeScript project and the tsc complains about the usage of the .remove method:

```
class Archive {
   documents: DocInfo[] = [];  // <-- Array of class DocInfo

   addDocument(document: DocInfo) {
      ...
   }

   deleteDocument(document: DocInfo) {
      this.documents.remove(document);
                     ^^^^^^
                     tsc complains here: TS2339:Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'DocInfo[]'
   }
}
```

How can I tell the tsc about this extension?

I tried creating a typings file, but without any success:

```
declare module 'Array' {
    export function removeByAttr(propertyName: string, propertyValue: any);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not make it a part of `DocType` itself.

Comment: The remove method needs to be part of an "Array" of DocType. Not on DocType itself!

Comment: Moving it to Array.prototype will make it available for any type of array.

Comment: @Rajesh I already created the polyfill on Array.prototype, but that is in plain javascript. The tsc does not know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typings should extend `Array<T>` interface:

```
interface Array<T> {
    remove(item: T): boolean;
}
```

Comment: Adding this code in a .d.ts file in my /typings folder did the trick!

Comment: Note, please suggest to use less generic name. This can have issues and might override original `Array.remove` function.

Comment: @Rajesh, `Array` has no `remove` function. And anyway the question is how to add typings.

Comment: Adding generic names in prototype is considered as bad practice because if  its added in future, your code will override it. Also I just asked you to add this caveat

Comment: @AlekseyL. It will use native code, but overridden typing. that's a problem

Answer (score 1):

Extending the Array class with an interface it's simple, you could try something like this:

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20remove(o%3A%20T)%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AArray.prototype.remove%20%3D%20function%20(o)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20idx%20%3D%20this.indexOf(o)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(idx%20!%3D%3D%20-1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.splice(idx%2C%201)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20DocInfo%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Archive%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20documents%3A%20DocInfo%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20addDocument(document%3A%20DocInfo)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.documents.push(document)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20deleteDocument(document%3A%20DocInfo)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.documents.remove(document)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20printDocuments()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.documents.forEach((item%3A%20DocInfo)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(item.name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20new%20Archive()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20_1%20%3D%20new%20DocInfo('1')%3B%0D%0Aconst%20_2%20%3D%20new%20DocInfo('2')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.addDocument(_1)%3B%0D%0Aa.addDocument(_2)%3B%0D%0Aa.printDocuments()%3B%0D%0Aa.deleteDocument(_1)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log('*********************')%3B%0D%0Aa.printDocuments()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log('*********************')%3B%0D%0Aa.addDocument(_1)%3B%0D%0Aa.deleteDocument(_2)%3B%0D%0Aa.printDocuments()%3B)

```
    interface Array<T> {
   remove(o: T): Array<T>;
}

Array.prototype.remove = function (o) {

    var idx = this.indexOf(o);
        if (idx !== -1) {
            return this.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    return this;
}

class DocInfo { 
    name: string ;
    constructor(name) { 
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Archive {
   documents: DocInfo[] = []; 
   addDocument(document: DocInfo) {
       this.documents.push(document);
   }
   deleteDocument(document: DocInfo) {
      this.documents.remove(document);
   }
   printDocuments() { 
       this.documents.forEach((item: DocInfo) => { 
           console.log(item.name);
       });

   }
}

const a = new Archive();
const _1 = new DocInfo('1');
const _2 = new DocInfo('2');

a.addDocument(_1);
a.addDocument(_2);
a.printDocuments();
a.deleteDocument(_1);
console.log('*********************');
a.printDocuments();
console.log('*********************');
a.addDocument(_1);
a.deleteDocument(_2);
a.printDocuments();
```

Comment: is there a way to make an array extension for only arrays that contain particular classes? ie. MyClass[] ?

Comment: @Gillardo sure with constraint, take a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html *Using Type Parameters in Generic Constraints*